# How can I find left and right limits as $x$ approaches nonremovable discontinuity?

Tags: calculus

The book says to "simplify, find crucial numbers, determine sign in intervals then determine limits."

$f(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-3)(x-2)}$

I don't understand what the directions mean. I know that the nonremovable is $x = 3$ and the removable is $x = 2$. What is the next step to "find left and right limits as $x$ approaches nonremovable discontinuity?"

Comment: The directions mean that you approach the value (here $x=3$ for example) from either the left or the right; so from the left would mean that you take $x=3-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$, and then consider the limit $\epsilon\to0$. From the right it would be $x=3+\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to0$. On the real line, it literally means approaching the point in question from the left or right (and in this example the left and right limits are different, and both don't exist).

Comment: Drawing your function might help you understand such things better.

Comment: I don't understand. "x=3−ϵ for ϵ>0" - is that the formula for approaching from the left? Is it always going to have a minus sign? What is e? How does this help in solving the problem? Am I supposed to solve the formula? If so, do I solve it for x or e? What's the difference between x and e?

How do I draw a function? How would a drawing help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating a limit, you are trying to determine what the value (if any) is of the function at some point. For example here we want to calculate
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)}.
\end{align}
We can already see that this limit is potentially going to be problematic, as $f(3)="2/0"$ (the quotation marks are there because dividing by zero is not a valid operation) does not exist. Now by definition a limit exists if the left, i.e.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 3-}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)},
\end{align}
and the right, i.e.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 3+}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)},
\end{align}
limits both exists and are equal to each other, and then we **define** the limit to be
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)}:=\lim_{x\to 3-}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)}=\lim_{x\to 3+}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)}.
\end{align}
It is important to consider left and right limits because functions can behave very differently at points, depending on whether these points are approached from the left or from the right. We thus see that we should actually always be talking about left and right limits, because a limit by definition only exists if these exist **and** are equal.

Now a number $L\in\mathbb{R}$ is a right limit (analogously for the leftt limit) of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as $x$ approaches some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that the implication $0<x-a<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Intuitively, this just means that as we get closer and closer to the point $a$ (from the right in this case), the function should come closer and closer to the point $L$.

As for calculating limits informally, it suffices to just "plug in" the value and see what comes out (but a formal proof would involve the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition, also if the limit doesn't exist). In this case then, for the left limit $x\to 3^-$, which just means "take $x$ to $3$ such that $|x|<3$", which is the same as saying that we approach the function from the left. This is what I algebraically expressed as $x=3-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$ ($\epsilon$ is just a dummy variable), then we can also write
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-3)}&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{(3-\epsilon-2)(3-\epsilon-1)}{(3-\epsilon-2)(3-\epsilon-3)} \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{2-\epsilon}{-\epsilon} \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\frac{-2}{\epsilon}-1\right) \\
&="-\infty",
\end{align}
where the quotation marks are there to remind you that $\pm\infty$ are not actual values. So the $x=3\pm\epsilon$ part is just a rewriting of the same limit (as $x\to 3^-$ is equivalent to $\epsilon\to0^+$ in $x=3-\epsilon$); I mentioned to emphasise what we are doing when approaching from the left/right. Doing the same calculation for the right limit should convince you that $\lim_{x\to3^+}((x-1)(x-2))/((x-2)(x-3))="\infty"$. So the limits are not the same, and they don't even exist, which is already enough to conclude that the limit at $x=3$ does not exist.

You draw a function as you have hopefully learned in high school; you draw a plane with two orthogonal axes, $x$ and $y$, and let $y=f(x)$, so calculating $f(x)$ and drawing the points $(x,f(x))$ gives you a way to plot the function. Try http://www.wolframalpha.com with this, just enter a function and it will show you a plot. Then for this function you can clearly see that the function shoots off to infinity in different directions at $x=3$, depending on which side you are.

Comment: How can you tell that the goal is to find x=3? What about x=2?

Comment: I just took this example because it's an example of how the left and right one differ. The case $x=2$ is also kind of trivial since filling $x=2$ gives an undetermined limit of the type $"0/0"$, which enables you to use L'Hopitals rule, so the limit equals -1.